# Error de sqlite3 usando Flask

Tags: python, base-de-datos, sqlite, flask

Cuando llamo una funcion de otro modulo para ejecutar una orde sql, me da el siguiente error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 13364 and this is thread id 10996.
```

Este es el codigo en el archivo principal:

```
@app.route("/Insertar/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])#Habilitar
def insertar():
    modelo = request.form["modelo"]
    marca = request.form["marca"]
    precio = request.form["precio"]
    color = request.form["color"]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        DB.crear(modelo, marca, precio, color)
    return render_template("Insert.html", modelo=modelo, marca=marca, precio=precio, color=color)
```

Y esta es la funcion importada:

```
import sqlite3

conexion = sqlite3.connect("BDFlask_Sqlite.db")


def crear(modelo, marca, precio, color):
    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO coches VALUES(NULL, '{modelo}', '{marca}', '{precio}', '{color}');")
    conexion.commit()
    conexion.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes desactivar esa comprobación cuando conectas con la base de datos.

```
sqlite3.connect("BDFlask_Sqlite.db", check_same_thread=False)
```

Comment: Cambie eso de lugar y lo puse dentro de la funcion, así funcionó :)

Comment: Sí, el problema es que lo están llevando a cabo hilos diferentes al estar en funciones distintas, pero en principio con el añadido del =False debería funcionar, con independencia de dónde realices la conexión.. En cualquier caso me alegro de que te haya funcionado :)